# Why does clang produces wrong results for my c code compiled with -O1 but not with -O0?

Tags: c, clang

For **input 0xffffffff**, the following c code works fine with no optimization, but produces wrong results **when compiled with -O1**. Other compilation options are -g -m32 -Wall. The code is tested with clang-900.0.39.2 in macOS 10.13.2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) return 1;

    char *endp;
    int x = (int)strtoll(argv[1], &endp, 0);

    int mask1 = 0x55555555;
    int mask2 = 0x33333333;
    int count = (x & mask1) + ((x >> 1) & mask1);

    int v1 = count >> 2;
    printf("v1 = %#010x\n", v1);

    int v2 = v1 & mask2;
    printf("v2 = %#010x\n", v2);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input: 0xffffffff**

Outputs with -O0: (expected)

> v1 = 0xeaaaaaaa
>
> v2 = 0x22222222

Outputs with -O1: (wrong)

> v1 = 0x2aaaaaaa
>
> v2 = 0x02222222

Below are disassembled instructions for the line "int v1 = count >> 2;" with -O0 and -O1.

With -O0:

> sarl   $0x2, %esi

With -O1:

> shrl   $0x2, %esi

Below are disassembled instructions for the line "int v2 = v1 & mask2;" with -O0 and -O1.

With -O0:

> andl   -0x24(%ebp), %esi      //-0x24(%ebp) stores 0x33333333

With -O1:

> andl   $0x13333333, %esi      ***//why does the optimization changes 0x33333333 to 0x13333333?***

In addition, if x is set to 0xffffffff locally instead of getting its value from arguments, the code will work as expected even with -O1.

P.S: The code is an experimental piece based on my solution to the Data Lab from the CS:APP course @ CMU. The lab asks the student to implement a function that counts the number of 1 bit of an int variable **without using any type other than int**.

Comment: `0xffffffff` is > `MAX_INT` in your case and overflow of `int` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Stargateur Are you sure? Shouldn't this be -1?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight signed overflow is used as exemple of undefined behavior, http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p3.

Comment: That said, I suggest you to use `unsigned int` for many reason, bit operator should only be use with `unsigned integer`, `printf("v1 = %#010x\n", v1);` => `%x` expect an `unsigned int` so it's undefined behavior to send an `int`.

Comment: can reproduce with clang .. I get the same (correct) output with gcc for both `-O0` and `-O1`

Comment: but I think the issue is right-shifting negative signed types is implementation-defined (and apparently clang and gcc handle this differently). Probably safest to confine bit operations to unsigned types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer

Comment: I'm surprised that it works at all due to the missing `#include` statements

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected command line parameter

Comment: this statement: `int count = (x & mask1) + ((x >> 1) & mask1);` will overflow the variable `count`  Suggest cast the expressions to `ssize_t` or better `int64_t` and declare `count` as being that longer type.

Comment: The code really needs to be checking that the parameter was actually entered by the user, otherwise the code will have a seg fault event when the function: `strtol()` is called

Comment: @Stargateur: Converting an overly large integer value to a signed integer type is not *undefined behavior*. It is *implementation-defined behavior*. Signed overflow causes undefined behavior when it happens during evaluation of arithmetic operators (this is what your link talks about). Overflow during *conversion* to a signed integer type is *implementation-defined* (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3). Only floating-point values can cause UB when converted to integer types.

Comment: This code suffers from "sloppy typing", meaning that the programmer did not give any thought about the size or signedness needed for their algorithm, they just typed `int` all over the place. "Sloppy typing" tends to lead to various forms of poorly-defined behavior bugs and always leads to completely non-portable code. Professional programmers use `stdint.h`.

Comment: @user3629249 Sorry for the missing parts. I just added the #include statements and argc checking.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the tip on stdint.h. The code is an experimental piece based on my solution to the Data Lab from the CS:APP course @ CMU. The lab asks the student to implement a function that counts the number of 1 bit of an int variable without using any type other than int. Now I understands right-shifting int has uncertainties, but I still don't understand why the optimization changes mask2 (0x33333333) to 0x13333333.

Comment: @ZackZhu No idea. gcc -O1 and -O3 do not change that mask in the disassembly.

Answer (score 2):

As several commenters have pointed out, right-shifting signed values is **not well defined**.

I changed the declaration and initialization of `x` to

```
unsigned int x = (unsigned int)strtoll(argv[1], &endp, 0);
```

and got consistent results under -O0 and -O1.  (But before making that change, I was able to reproduce your result under clang under MacOS.)

Comment: I can confirm changing the type of x to unsigned removed the inconsistency. But I still don't understand why the optimization changes mask2 to 0x13333333.

Comment: @ZackZhu I don't quite understand, either, although it could simply be the difference between shifting in a 0 or shifting in a 1 at the left edge.  But, to me, it's not even an interesting question.  Although what we're talking about here is implementation-defined behavior, rather than undefined, much of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087286/c-program-crashes-when-adding-an-extra-int/37087465#37087465) applies.

Answer (score 2):

As you have discovered, you raise *Implementation-defined Behavior* in your attempt to store `0xffffffff` (`4294967295`) in `int x` (where `INT_MAX` is `7fffffff`, or `2147483647`). [C11 Standard §6.3.1.3 (draft n1570) - Signed and unsigned integers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3) Whenever using `strtoll` (or `strtoull`) (both versions with 1-`l` would be fine) and attempting to store the value as an `int`, you must check the result against `INT_MAX` before making the assignment with a cast. (or if using exact width types, against `INT32_MAX`, or `UINT32_MAX` for unsigned)

Further, in circumstance such as this where bit operations are involved, you can remove uncertainty and insure portability by using the exact width types provided in `stdint.h` and the associated *format specifiers* provided in `inttypes.h`. Here, there is no need for use of a signed `int`. It would make more sense to handle all values as `unsigned` (or `uint32_t`).

For example, the following provides a default value for the input to avoid the *Undefined Behavior* invoked if your code is executed without argument (you can also simply test `argc`), replaces the use of `strtoll` with `strtoul`, validates the input fits within the associated variable before assignment handling the error if it does not, and then makes use of the unambiguous exact types, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    uint64_t tmp = argc > 1 ? strtoul (argv[1], NULL, 0) : 0xffffffff;

    if (tmp > UINT32_MAX) {
        fprintf (stderr, "input exceeds UINT32_MAX.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    uint32_t x = (uint32_t)tmp,
        mask1 = 0x55555555,
        mask2 = 0x33333333,
        count = (x & mask1) + ((x >> 1) & mask1),
        v1 = count >> 2,
        v2 = v1 & mask2;

    printf("v1 = 0x%" PRIx32 "\n", v1);

    printf("v2 = 0x%" PRIx32 "\n", v2);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/masktst
v1 = 0x2aaaaaaa
v2 = 0x22222222
```

**Compiled with**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o bin/masktst masktst.c
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Converting an overly large integer value to a signed integer type is not *undefined behavior*. It is *implementation-defined behavior*.

Comment: Good point, it is the finer points of the 'defined' verbiage that tripped me up. (the Annex J.2 or J.3) The actual standard reference (outside the Annex) is [6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3) Whether undefined or implementation defined -- it is something I try to avoid like the plague...

Answer (score -2):

this statement:

```
int x = (int)strtoll(argv[1], &endp, 0);
```

results in a signed overflow, which is undefined behavior.

(on my system, the result is: -1431655766

The resulting values tend to go downhill from there:

The variable: `v1` receives: -357913942

The variable: `v2` receives: 572662306

the `%x` format specifier only works correctly with unsigned variables

Comment: This is out-of-range conversion, not overflow. See 6.3.1.3/3 for behaviour of out-of-range conversion (which is not UB).

Comment: Or, it would be if OP actually included `stdlib.h` -- as is, the call to `strtoll` is a constraint violation in C99 for calling undeclared function (and `strtoll` did not exist in C89)