# My code functions with a printf statement, but not without it

Tags: c

Adding the printf("Hi!\n") statements allows the code to work. It also works if the bound initial bound is improper and the user enters a new one. When I ran some tests calculate divers sometimes returned a character instead of an integer. I'm thinking it has something to do with my memory allocation. I also noticed that ./a.out 6 10 "|" would work but ./a.out 6 25 "|" would not causing an infinite loop when printing the lines of "|".

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Structs
typedef struct data_struct {
    int lineNumber;
    int divisorSum;
    char type[10];
}data;

// Prototypes
int calculateDivsors(int integer);

// Functions
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int lowerBound;
    int upperBound;
    char character;

    // Gets the values from command-line
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &lowerBound);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &upperBound);
    sscanf(argv[3], "%c", &character);

    // Check to see if bound is proper
    while (upperBound <= lowerBound || lowerBound < 2) {
        printf("Error, please enter a new range (positive increasing).\n");
        scanf("%d %d", &lowerBound, &upperBound);
    }

    // Structure calls
    data* info = NULL;
    int totalData = upperBound - lowerBound;

    // Allocate the memory
    info = (data*)malloc(totalData * sizeof(data));

    printf("Hi!\n");

    if (info != NULL) {
        // Iterate through all the digits between the two bounds
        for (int i = lowerBound; i <= upperBound; i++) {
            int sum = calculateDivsors(i);


            // Write data to indiviual structures
            info[i].lineNumber = i;
            info[i].divisorSum = sum;

            // Check to see if the sum is greater than, less than, or equal to the original
            if (sum == i) {
                strcpy(info[i].type, "Perfect");
            }

            else if (sum > i) {
                strcpy(info[i].type, "Abundant");
            }

            else if (sum < i) {
                strcpy(info[i].type, "Deficient");
            }

            // Line n# has a column width of 4, string of 10
            printf("%4d is %-10s\t", info[i].lineNumber, info[i].type);

            // Generate Pictogram
            for (int j = 0; j < info[i].divisorSum; j++) {
                printf("%c", character);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

    }
}

// Adds up the sum of diviors
int calculateDivsors(int integer) {

    int sum = 0; 

    for (int i = 1; i < integer; i++) {
        // Add to sum if perfectly i is a sum of integer
         if (integer % i == 0) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }

 return sum; // Returns the sum of diviors
}
```

Comment: Can you please give the output as text?

Comment: it neither functions with the `printf` nor without it.

Comment: You have at least one out of range causing heap overrun in this code. The index `i` used for `info[i]` indexing of your allocation is not zero based, but the allocation size, `totalData`, *is* (correctly, btw). Therefore, as `i` increases it will breach `totalSize` and in so doing, you're program invokes undefined behavior. Also totalData should be sized as `int totalData = upperBound - lowerBound + 1;`

Comment: Its working for me on my Mac OS terminal. Why would that be?

Comment: Undefined behavior doesn't mean it gets an error. Anything can happen, including the appearance of working.

Comment: When you have a buffer overrun, sometimes it overwrites something important and causes an error, other times it overwrites something that isn't used so you don't notice the problem.

Comment: *Its working for me... Why would that be?* See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087286/c-program-crashes-when-adding-an-extra-int/37087465#37087465) to a similar question.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ahh I see. I resolved the issue; thank you.

Comment: You should seriously ask yourself why you're dynamic-allocating *anything* in this program. There is no need. Each iteration is completely independent of the others, and that includes *all* output. Therefore, a single `data` record populated and dumped within each iteration should print what you want, and avoid the mistake you made of mishandling dynamic sizing and indexing in the first place.

Comment: You can never know whether a `sscanf` conversion succeeds or fails without ***checking the return***.

Comment: BIWOMM, the most famous of all defenses of buggy code: "But it works on MY machine!"

Comment: @CareyGregory In fairness, though, the exclamation of BIWOMM is not necessarily a defense.  It's probably honest confusion: "Okay, so if it's wrong, then why did it work?" (The concept that undefined behavior can do *anything* is *very* hard to get at first.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I completely agree and I admit to having said BIWOMM myself many times. It's a difficult lesson to learn because the reasons for it can be many, and it takes most people years, myself included.

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing data outside its allocated buffer whenever lowerBound doesn't start with 0.

```
info[i].lineNumber = i;
```

Ideally, you should become...

```
info[i - lowerBound].lineNumber = i;
```

To ensure that the indexing starts at 0. Further, your window between `lowerBound` and `upperBound` is *inclusive*. That means it includes *both* ending boundaries. Therefore, `totalData` is undersized by one element. Even if you fix the indexing problem, your code will *still* be wrong with this:

```
int totalData = (upperBound - lowerBound) + 1;
```

Failing to do both of the above causes your code to invoke *undefined behavior* (UB), and thus unpredictable results thereafter. It may even *appear* to work. That, however, is a red herring when your code has UB. Don't confuse *defined* behavior with *observed* behavior. You can trust the latter only once you have the former; the two are not synonymous.