# Why does printf print 0s when I wrongly returned pointer to value on the stack only when optimizing with gcc compiler?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, compiler-optimization

I am trying to understand the behavior of printf in this example. of course the main issue here is that we are returning a pointer to a value on the stack that was popped after the function Boo returned.

I compiled with gcc. In test1: I got 7 printed twice which was expected. And a garbage value on the second printf in test2. but **when I compiled with gcc -O3 I got 0 printed on both cases** and a compiler warning about returning address of local variable.

> test.c: In function ‘Foo’:
> test.c:8:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
> return t;
> ^
> test.c:5:9: note: declared here
> int j;

Can someone help me explain how does the behavior of printf that causes this behavior?

```
int *Boo(int i, int *p)
{
    int j;
    int *t = &j;
    *t = i + *p;
    return t;
}

void Foo(int x)
{
    if (x == 0) { return;}
    Foo(x - 1);
}

//test1
int main(void)
{
    int x = 5;
    int *t = Boo(2, &x);
    printf("%d", *t);
    printf("%d", *t);

    return 0;
}

//test2
int main(void)
{
    int x = 5;
    int *t = Boo(2, &x);
    
    printf("%d", *t);
    Foo(8);
    printf("%d", *t);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The reason for the observed behaviour is not `printf()`... it's the programmer's fault who allowed UB

Comment: Because undefined behavior is undefined. So a compiler might do different weird things especially if compiling with different settings.

Comment: *I got 7 printed twice which was expected.* It's expected **not** to print 7 on either occasion. If you did get 7 it's only because the location had not yet been re-used.

Comment: thank you, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087286/c-program-crashes-when-adding-an-extra-int/37087465#37087465) this does answer the first part, but I was just curious if there is an explanation to why specifically on optimization printf will print 0s only, I tried looking into assembly code but I could not deduce anything from that.

Comment: You could single-step with a debugger to observe what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC sees that `Boo` returns a pointer to a local variable, and that therefore any attempt to use this pointer is undefined behavior.  That means, according to the C standard, that the compiler can do whatever it wants, and in such cases GCC will often generate code that's "efficient" even if it is totally unrelated to what the programmer may have intended.  It inlines the call to `Boo`, which has no visible effects and therefore is optimized away, and it picks an "efficient" way to provide an argument for `printf`, which happens to be the constant 0.

See on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jvsTvP).  The integer argument to `printf` goes in `esi`, which comes from `ebp` which is zeroed.  I guess there's a missed optimization in that it saves the same 0 in `ebp` across the call to `printf` to reload into `esi`, instead of just re-zeroing `esi` afterward.  But the whole analysis is kind of pointless since, again, the behavior is undefined.

`Boo` itself is optimized into a function that just returns a `NULL` pointer and does nothing else, which again is legal because of undefined behavior, but that version of `Boo` is not called by the program.  `Foo` is also optimized into a function which returns immediately without recursing; the compiler can tell that the recursive calls have no effect.  (And if a negative argument were passed to `Foo`, you'd have undefined behavior due to signed integer overflow, so the compiler need not handle that case.)