# using array of chars and strdup, getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, char, strdup

Suppose i write,

```
char **p;
p[0] = strdup("hello");
```

Strdup creates a duplicate string in heap with ending character '\0'; As p is pointer to pointer of char, p[0] = strdup("hello") seems perfectly fine for me. But why am i getting segmentation fault.

Comment: `p` points nowhere.  So `p[0]` is noplace, and you can't store `strdup`'s return value there.

Comment: Maybe `char **p` -> `char *p[10]`. Or just `char *p; p = strdup(...`, depending on what you're trying to achieve. With `char *p[10]`, `p` is an array of 10 pointers to char, each of them pointing initially nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a simpler example.  Suppose you say

```
int *ip;
ip[0] = 5;
```

`ip` is a pointer to one or more `int`s -- but it's not initialized, so it points nowhere, so `ip[0]` isn't a valid memory location, so we can't store the value 5 there.

In the same way, when you said

```
char **p;
```

`p` is a pointer that points nowhere.  If it *did* point somewhere, it would point to another pointer.  But it doesn't point anywhere, so

```
p[0] = strdup("hello");
```

blows up.

To fix this, you need to make `p` point somewhere, and specifically to memory allocated to hold one or more pointers.  There are many ways to do this:

```
char *q;
p = &q;                                 /* way 1 */

char *a[10];
p = a;                                  /* way 2 */

p = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));        /* way 3 */
```

or instead of using a pointer, use an array to start with:

```
char *p[10];                            /* way 4 */
```

After any of those, `p[0] = strdup("hello")` should work.

For way 3, we would also need to check that `malloc` succeeded (that it dd not return a null pointer).

For ways 2 through 4, we could also set `p[1]` through `p[9]`.  But for way 1, only `p[0]` is valid.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087286/c-program-crashes-when-adding-an-extra-int/37087465#37087465) to a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087286) for more discussion about trying to use uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There is declared an uninitialized pointer that has an indeterminate value.

```
char **p;
```

so dereferencing the pointer in this expression `p[0]` (that is equivalent to the expression `*p`) used in this statement

```
p[0] = strdup("hello");
```

invokes undefined behavior because there is an attempt to write to memory using an incorrect pointer value of the expression `p[0]`.

You could write either for example

```
char *s;
char **p = &s;
p[0] = strdup("hello");
```

Or

```
char **p = malloc( sizeof( char * ) );
p[0] = strdup("hello");
```

That is the pointer to pointer `p` must point to a valid object. Thus dereferencing the pointer you will get a valid object of the type `char *` that will be assigned by the value returned by the call of `strdup`..