# String literal in C giving null value

Tags: c, string-literals

I have this piece of code. I tried to run it on ideone in C language (gcc 8.3).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char* final;
    *final='a';
    *(final+1)='b';
    *(final+2)='c';
    *(final+3)='\0'; //mark 2
    
    printf("final: %c \n",*final);
    printf("final: %c \n",*(final+1));
    printf("final: %c \n",*(final+2));
    
    printf("final all: %s \n",final); //mark 1
    return 0;
}
```

The marked line 1 prints null value.

```
Output:
final: a 
final: b 
final: c 
final all: (null)
```

Q1. What could be the reason of the null value?

Q2. How to print the correct value i.e. `abc`.

Thanks.

Also, the mark 2 doesn't make any difference here. I know we use that in an array of chars. I tried to see if that makes any difference but it still prints null value.

Comment: `char* final;` does not point anywhere, as the compiler should have warned about.

Comment: You are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer which is undefined behavior. Apparently `char* final` gets the value 0 which is specifically handled by `printf` to print the result `(null)`, and your system does not report an error or crash when you dereference a NULL pointer and store data at this address.

Comment: If you turn on compiler warnings (using `-Wall`), you'll see you get a warning: `<source>:6:11: warning: 'final' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]`. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: I had used an online compiler on ideone.com. I am going to try on codeblocks. Thank you all for pointing that out.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087286), which is almost a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using a value of uninitialized non-static local variable `final`, which is indeterminate. The output of first 3 `printf()`s seems happened to be what are expected thanks to the optimization.

Initialize the variable by allocating some memory to fix.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char* final;
    final=malloc(4); /* allocate memory and assign */
    if(final==NULL) return 1; /* check if allocation succeeded */
    *final='a';
    *(final+1)='b';
    *(final+2)='c';
    *(final+3)='\0'; //mark 2
    
    printf("final: %c \n",*final);
    printf("final: %c \n",*(final+1));
    printf("final: %c \n",*(final+2));
    
    printf("final all: %s \n",final); //mark 1
    free(final); /* free what is allocated */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the fact that it prints (null) for final is presumably because the printf function has a specific test for null pointers when printing with format %s, so it can print (null) instead of blowing up.

Comment: Thank you @MikeCAT. I now understand the reason for the null value. I'll change accordingly.