# how does adding a line of prtintf fix this?

Tags: c

I am new to the C language (I started to learn it a week ago). the program was having some random output so i wanted to see what was it storing in the variable. then the printf fixed it somehow.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int laske(float lista[]);

const int MAX = 3;

int main()
{

  float lista[5], yhteispisteet;

  int counter = 0;

  do
  {
    printf("Anna %d. pisteet: \n", counter +1);

    scanf("%f", &lista[counter++] );

      printf("%d",lista[counter]); <-- if you remove this line it dosent work

  }
  while (counter < MAX);
  yhteispisteet = laske(lista);

  
  printf("\nYhteispisteet ovat: %.2f\n", yhteispisteet);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}

int laske(float lista[])

{

   int rivi, tulos;

   for (rivi=0; rivi< MAX; rivi++)

    tulos = tulos + lista[rivi];

   return tulos;

}
```

Comment: `tulos = tulos + lista[rivi];` is *undefined behaviour* because `tulos` has not been initialised. This gives the "random output".

Comment: `printf("%d",lista[counter]);` is also *undefined behaviour* because `lista[counter]` has not been initialised **and** because `%d` is the wrong format specifier.

Comment: And note that summing floating point numbers into an integer will truncate them. Assigning the integer sum returned into a `float` will not recover the lost information.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings, as a first step. Then fix them.

Comment: @WeatherVane `lista[counter]` is initialized right before the printf statement. The rest of your comment is valid though.

Comment: @kyriakosSt it was not. Please take note of the `counter++` in the line right before the printf statement. This `lista[counter]` has **not** been set. It won't be set until the next iteration.

Comment: Possible explanation why the `printf();` heals the problem: For sure printf will use a bunch of local variables. It may leave them behind on the stack with a value of zero. The function `int laske()` recycles that unused but zeroed memory space for the uninitialized variable `int tulos`. Undefined behaviour at its best.

Comment: Why does adding a `printf` call change the result?  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087286#37087465), and skim down to where it says "Now, I've said a lot here, but I realize I haven't actually gotten around to answering the question".  (That answer is talking about adding a local variable, but the arguments for adding a `printf` call are basically the same.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things to note from your code:

1. You are adding a `float` and an `int` when you do: `tulos = tulos + lista[rivi];`, without casting the input float to int like this: `tulos = tulos + (int)lista[rivi];` Or better yet, just declare `tulos` as `float`, and return a float from your `laske` function, because the return value is again being assigned to a float `yhteispisteet`
2. You assign to `lista[counter++]` with the `scanf`, and then increment the counter (post-increment) and print the `lista[counter]`(which is printing the incremented indexed value that did not take any assignments yet). It is better to increment `counter++` after the printf function.
3. You did not initialize your variable `tulos`, and this gives you undefined behavior when your code is running, which is probably what you are seeing when you add and then remove the `printf` and then rerun